# Get BPL File Name

Tags: delphi, bpl

From within a BPL, is it possible to get its own file name?   e.g. C:\foo\bar.bpl

(dynamically loaded and delphi7, if it matters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197.aspx). For the module handle, use [`SysInit.HInstance`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysInit.HInstance). Passing zero will give you the host EXE's file name instead, also known as [`ParamStr(0)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.ParamStr).

Answer (score 1):

Example use of GetModuleFileName:

```
function  DLLFileName : string;
begin
  SetLength(Result,MAX_PATH);
  GetModuleFileName(HInstance,PCHar(Result),MAX_PATH);
  SetLength(Result,StrLen(PChar(Result)));
end;
```

Comment: The last two lines can be folded into one, as `GetModuleFileName()` returns the number of characters copied, so the `StrLen()` isn't necessary.

Comment: It's even easier:
Result := PChar(Result);

Comment: @dummzeuch: Looks easier, yes. Calls the equivalent of `StrLen()` internally anyway. For those that crave the smallest and fastest code...